# Behat+Mink+Selenium installation

Tags: symfony, selenium, behat, mink

I'm getting error below when trying to install Behat+Mink+Selenium. What could be the solution?

**php composer.phar install**

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.4.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.4.x-dev].
    - symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.4.x-dev requires behat/behat 2.4.*@stable -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

**Composer.json:**

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "behat/behat": "2.4.*@stable",
        "behat/mink": "1.4.*@stable",
        "behat/mink-extension": "*",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "*",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "*",
        "behat/symfony2-extension": "*",
        "behat/mink-browserkit-driver":  "*",
        "behat/mink-sahi-driver": "*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin/"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm following these two blogs to install it:

- [Installing, configuring and running Behat on Symfony2 with Mink and
  Selenium](http://www.kadeke.be/en/developer-blog/behat-testing)
  [Installing Behat, Mink and Selenium2 for Symfony2](http://www.forouzani.com/installing-behat-mink-and-selenium2-in-symfony2.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, you have registered too many packages. For example, behat is a dependency of the symfony2-extension. So, just need to require the symfony2-extension and behat will be required :) The problem when you require everything explicitly is you need to check if every packages constraints can work together on packagist (which can becomes a pain)...

For a Symfony 2.4 project, I would use the following packages:

```
"require-dev": {
    "behat/symfony2-extension": "~1.1",
    "behat/mink-extension": "~1.3",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "~1.1",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "~1.0",
}
```

Comment: How does one know what version numbers to use?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest run composer require, and before you installing do a composer update so that all dependencies are at updated version. So the below dependencie were usesful for my symfony2.8 project:

```
composer update
composer require behat/behat
composer require behat/symfony2-extension
composer require behat/mink
composer require behat/mink-browserkit-driver
composer require behat/mink-extension
composer require behat/mink-goutte-driver
composer require behat/mink-selenium2-driver
composer require emuse/behat-html-formatter
composer require coduo/php-matcher
```